# Integration testing with Quarkus and Redis how do I set a state with the redis?

Tags: java, testing, redis, integration, quarkus

Hi I have my test class annotated with the

```java
@QuarkusIntegrationTest
```

I wanna run the following test

```java
        given()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .pathParam("id", id)
                .when()
                .get("/user/presence/{id}")
                .then()
                .statusCode(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode())
    }
```

This gets the user presence and the presence is stored inside a redis cache.

I wanna do a setup step that puts the presence into my redis cache before the test begins. However, my redis cache is not exposed on any endpoint so i'm not able to set it via HTTP calls.

The redis class i want to test is

```java
@ApplicationScoped
```

This seems to be needed since the constructor sets a RedisDataSoruce

```java
    public MyRedisCache(RedisDataSource ds) {
        this.commands = ds.string(MyClass.class);
    }
```

But this makes me unable to use this perticular class instance inside my integration tests. So how can I put values into this redis before my test begins

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, in `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` it's not possible to inject any bean to help.
I'd recommend using a library to connect to Redis and put a value into the cache directly.

You can use for example [Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) or [Jedis](https://github.com/redis/jedis), and add it to your project with `test` dependency scope. (You could also check for and use the underlying Redis client already included via the Quarkus plugin you use for Redis)

Then, you could add code to the test class in a `@BeforeAll` method to call the library and add data directly to Redis programmatically.